# Как правильно загрузить файл с React/Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно загрузить фото с React, так как приходит только имя файла, а не сам файл.

**component.js**

```
export default class Home extends Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.fileInput = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert(
      `Selected file - ${
        this.fileInput.current.files[0].name
        }`
    );
    this.props.photoAdd(this.fileInput.current.files[0].name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType='multipart/form-data'>
        <label>
          Upload ----file:
          <input type='file' ref={this.fileInput} />
        </label>
        <br/>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**action.js**

```
export function photoAdd (photo)
{
  const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

  const requestBody =  'photo='+ photo ;
  const formData = {file: photo}

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
  }

  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: ADDPHOTO_REQUEST
    })

    axios.post('/api/addpic', formData, config)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADDPHOTO_SUCCESS,
          payload: response,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADDPHOTO_FAIL,
          payload: error
        })
      })
  }
}
```

**addpic.php**

```
public function addpic(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $name = mb_strtoupper($user->name[0]);
    $input=$request->all();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $filename= md5($_FILES['image']['name']).'.img';
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $file->move(public_path() . '/gallery',$filename);

        $success='yeah!!!';
    } else {
        $success = 'oh no';
    }

    return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData) а обычный объект.

Попробуйте вместо

```
const formData = {file: photo}
```

Этот вариант:

```
const formData = new FormData()
```

Вы можете добавлять пару ключ/значение с помощью FormData.append:

```
formData.append('file', myFileInput.files[0])
```

Если через photo как у вас:

```
formData.append('file', photo)
```

Но photo должен быть объектом [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File).

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)